# How to add arduino libraries to espressif IDE?

Tags: arduino-ide, can-bus, arduino-esp32, adafruit, espressif-idf

We are working on a project which requires CAN communication in it. We have made some code in the Arduino IDE which we are trying to do in ESP IDE. However, there are some libraries which we are finding difficult to import into the esp IDE, example (Adafruit). Is there any way we can do it?

We cloned the Arduino as component library from the github and made the necessary changes into some basic codes such as wifi scan from arduino IDE which worked successfully in the espressif IDE , we tried the same method and cloned the Adafruit libraries for OLED and MLX sensor but each time we tried to build program, it highlighted the library includation line and said "no such file or directory exits", we expect for a method to resolve this issue.

Comment: What version of the IDE are you using? 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: esp IDF version 4.4.3

Answer (score -1):

You can install libraries from a local ZIP file or by using the built-in library manager.

Go to Sketch > Include Library > Manage Libraries. Type a name in and find the one that you want to install and click install.

Comment: I want to add libraries of arduino in "espressif IDE" for esp32.

Comment: I see. I don't know that IDE. From some research, I see that you create a custom ESP-IDF component, add "arduino" as a dependency, and then run the "git submodule add (arduino library)" CLI. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.